# Passing parameter PHP to JavaScript results in "Unexpected Token error"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, uncaught-exception

I need to pass a parameter from PHP to JavaScript, so I do this:

```
    var title='<?php echo ($home->title); ?>';

console.log(title);
```

but I obtain

```
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Can anyone help me?

This is the output:

```
  var titolo_it='<p><strong>ddddddddddd</strong></p>
';
```

Comment: Is there an apostrophe (`'`) character in the string you're outputting from PHP?

Comment: what is the output of $home->title ?

Comment: this is the output

Answer (score 1):

The line break in `$home->title` is breaking the JavaScript syntax. You cannot include a literal line break in a JavaScript string that way.

To fix this, you need to be sure the data is properly encoded, so any apostrophes, line breaks, etc. are in proper format for JavaScript. Use the built-in function [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), like this:

```
var title=<?php echo json_encode($home->title); ?>;

console.log(title);
```

Comment: after I need to put the value in a textarea and If I use json_encode in my text area I read the " "

Comment: If you want to display it in a textarea, you will also need `htmlentities`, as in `json_encode(htmlentities($home->title))`.